# How do AWS CodeCommit active users really works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

Despite AWS CodeCommit documentation and FAQs, I don't understand how active users are defined and how they're charged. If we go to [FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/faqs/), we may find:

> Q: What is the definition of an active user in AWS CodeCommit?
>
> An active user is any unique AWS identity (IAM user/role, federated user, or root account) that accesses AWS CodeCommit repositories during the month, either through Git requests or by using the AWS Management Console. A server accessing CodeCommit using a unique AWS identity counts as an active user.
>
> Q: Which Git requests are considered towards the monthly allowance?
>
> A Git request includes any push or pull that transmits repository objects. The request does not count towards your Git request allowance if there is no object transfer due to local and remote branches being up-to-date.

but still, I have some doubts.

1. How much time does a user need to access CodeCommit to be an active user? If I access only 5, 10, 15 or 25 days in the first month and after don't access anymore, I'd be an active user on that month? If I access one day each month, am I an active user?
2. If I create a Lambda which doesn't perform "requests includes any push or pull that transmits repository objects", for instance, I call only `ListPullRequests` action using SDK, then will I be charged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How much time does a user need to access CodeCommit to be an active user?

Just one call to any one of following CodeCommit API is enough to make that unique role/user an active user.

- GetBranch[1]
- GitPull[2]
- GitPush[2]

> If I access only 5, 10, 15 or 25 days in the first month and after don't access anymore, I'd be an active user on that month?

Yes

> If I access one day each month, am I an active user?

Yes

Also note, CodeCommit pricing for the first 5 active users, it is 0$ providing Unlimited repositories, 50 GB-month of storage, 10,000 Git requests/month and for Each additional active user beyond the first 5, AWS CodeCommit costs $1 per active user per month. For every active user, your account receives an additional allowance of 10 GB-month of storage and 2,000 Git requests for that month. Unused allowance for storage and Git requests does not carry over to later months.

> If I create a Lambda which doesn't perform "requests includes any push or pull that transmits repository objects", for instance, I call only ListPullRequests action using SDK, then will I be charged?

Yes, this call will not be charged. As highlighted that Git requests includes any push or pull that transmits repository objects. The request does not count towards your Git request allowance if there is no object transfer due to local and remote branches being up-to-date.

Ref:

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/APIReference/API_GetBranch.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/auth-and-access-control-permissions-reference.html#aa-git